# Browser truncates port number in the address

Tags: android, redirect, web

I'm having the following issue: I'v developed a Tomcat and Apache based webapp (at `http://82.xx.xx.xx:8030/app`) which works fine when it's accessed through desktop browsers and mobile browsers. But now, I tried to access by a new Android 4.0 tablet and when I log into the app, the browser (default android browser and chrome) throws a message saying the url `http://82.xx.xx.xx/app` is not available.

The issue is the browser removes the port, has somebody any idea what can I do to solve this?

Comment: [SOLVED] I was becoming mad by spending a lot of time reviewing my code and thinking I had wrong code, but the problem was solved by changing the "APN Proxy" configuration of the tablet.<br/>
It's great because it is not my fault but it's a pity because my customers must change their config.
<br/><br/>
I hope it can help to other people.